# is in-system programming the same with the c++ programming?

Tags: c++

we are having a project about mobile robotics.and we are using atmel atmega128 microcontroller.what i've read was only in-system programming is used for that type of microcontrollerr..but can we use c++ for that type of microcontroller

Comment: If there is a C++ compiler/code generator for that system, then yes. If not, then no.

Answer (score 1):

In system programming is a technique/ability of programming the executable code into the device while it is populated in the target system. It has nothing to do with the language used to write those programs.

There do appear to be C++ compilers that target that device, following a quick search of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. `IAR Embedded Workbench` and `avr-gcc` are among the compilers which support C++ with **atmega128**.